# Insert SQL enum with jOOQ in PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, gradle, jooq

I'm trying to use jOOQ to insert a SQL enum in my database.

The database migration is setup with Liquibase like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">

    <changeSet id="202105031559" author="pk">
        <sql>CREATE TYPE my_type AS ENUM ('TYPE_A', 'TYPE_B')</sql>

        <createTable tableName="a">
            <column name="type" type="my_type" defaultValue='TYPE_A'>
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
        
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

The default enum value in the migration works as expected.

Trying to use jOOQ to insert the enum:

```
var result = dslContext
        .insertInto(A,
                A.TYPE
        )
        .values(
                MyType.TYPE_B
        )
        .execute();
```

Triggers the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "type" is of type my_type but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

My jOOQ configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JooqConfig {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public JooqConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultDSLContext dsl() {
        Settings settings = new Settings()
                .withRenderNameCase(RenderNameCase.LOWER)
                .withRenderQuotedNames(RenderQuotedNames.NEVER)
                .withExecuteLogging(true);
        return new DefaultDSLContext(connectionProvider(), SQLDialect.POSTGRES, settings);
    }

}
```

My Gradle setup:

```
jooq {
    version.set(dependencyManagement.importedProperties["jooq.version"])
    edition.set(nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition.OSS)

    configurations {
        create("main") {
            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                generator.apply {
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase"
                        withProperties(
                            org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property()
                                .withKey("scripts")
                                .withValue("src/main/resources/db/changelog/changelog-ddl.xml"),
                            org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property()
                                .withKey("includeLiquibaseTables")
                                .withValue("false"),
                            org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property()
                                .withKey("database.liquibaseSchemaName")
                                .withValue("public"),
                            org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property()
                                .withKey("changeLogParameters.contexts")
                                .withValue("!test"),
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone got any ideas how to insert the enum with jOOQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.15, the `org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase` translates the DDL statements to H2 and simulates a migration on an in-memory H2 database. This means you can't use vendor specific PostgreSQL features (H2 supports enums, but they have many flaws).

Instead, the recommended approach would be to use [testcontainers](https://testcontainers.org) and an actual PostgreSQL database for code generation. Some ideas on how to do this are documented in this issue: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6551 or in this example: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/main/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-testcontainers-example